# Python Error Catching & FTP

Tags: python, ftp

Trying to get a handle on the FTP library in Python. :)

Got this so far.

```
from ftplib import FTP

server = '127.0.0.1'
port = '57422'

print 'FTP Client (' + server + ') port: ' + port

try:
    ftp = FTP()
    ftp.connect(server, port, 3)
    print 'Connected! Welcome msg is \"' + ftp.getwelcome() + '\"'

    ftp.cwd('\\')

    x = '1'
    currentDir = ''

except: //***What do I put here?***
```

http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html
says there are several error codes I can catch but I can't do

except: ftplib.all_errors

Second question. :P
How can I retrieve more specific information on the error? Perhaps the error code?

Very new to python (an hour in or so).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write

```
except Exception, e:  #you can specify type of Exception also
   print str(e)
```

Comment: This is way too generic, `except ftblib.all_errors` is a more correct answer while still covering all ftp errors

Answer (score 24):

> I can't do

```
except: ftplib.all_errors
```

Of course not, that's simply bad syntax!  But of course you can do it with proper syntax:

```
except ftplib.all_errors:
```

i.e., the colon *after* the tuple of exceptions.

> How can I retrieve more specific
>   information on the error? Perhaps the
>   error code?

```
except ftplib.all_errors as e:
  errorcode_string = str(e).split(None, 1)[0]
```

E.g., `'530'` will now be the value of `errorcode_string` when the complete error message was `'530 Login authentication failed'`.

You can find the rest of the exception in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.error_reply).

Comment: name 'ftplib' is not defined when I try what you suggested (the original mistake was a typo)

Not sure on what to do so far. I thought I had the 'namespace' imported already.

Comment: @bobber, no, you need to add an `import ftplib` statement.  You didn't import the **module** -- you only imported a class from within the module (a practice which I personally detest, but that's another issue); so, to access qualified names such as `ftplib.all_errors`, you _also_ need to `import ftplib`.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You dont want to try catch an Exception class unless you have to. Exception is a catch all, instead catch the specific class being thrown, socket.error

```
  import ftplib
  import socket <--

  server = '127.0.0.1'
  port = '57422'

  print 'FTP Client (' + server + ') port: ' + port

  ftp = ftplib.FTP()
  try:
    ftp.connect(server, port, 3)
    print 'Connected! Welcome msg is \"' + ftp.getwelcome() + '\"'

    ftp.cwd('\\')

    x = '1'
    currentDir = ''
  except socket.error,e: <--
    print 'unable to connect!,%s'%e
```